# How to build a regular expression pattern?

Tags: regex

When I create postal code regular express pattern which requires 10 alphanumeric of fixed length. For example,canadian postal code format: alpha,numeric,alpha,numeric,alpha,numeric, left-justify and pad with spaces to meet the fixed length.

The pattern length should be fixed, the postal code length depends on different countries.
How can I do that?

Comment: Your best bet is going to use the regex that correlates to the country you're validating. Anything else is just saying it's valid for what it is, with no relation to the context of a country. (i.e. neither "10108" nor "E1 8EU" are valid for Canada)

Answer (score 1):

What language are you using?  Chances are that someone has already written this for you and released it somewhere.  For example, if you're using Perl, then the Regexp::Common module on CPAN has well-tested code for you to use.

Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: So look for a library in VB.net that does Canadian postal code validation, rather than rewriting it yourself.